# jQuery Deep linking, load content from div in other page issues

Tags: html, jquery, loading

I was able to set up a function where upon clicking the nav link it loads the "#content" div from the appropriate page into the "#content" div on the current page. The issue arose when I tried implementing deep linking with the address plugin. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to load just the "#content" div from a page.

You can see it live here: [www.theeastcoastclassic.com/index1.html](http://www.theeastcoastclassic.com/index1.html)
The bottom nav still has the original .load function, the top is using the deep linking function.

Here's my .js file:

```
// Deep Linking

    function loadURL(url) {
            console.log("loadURL: " + url);
            $("#content").load(url);
    }
    
    $.address.init(function(event) { 
            console.log("init: " + $('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
            }).change(function(event) {
            $("#content").load($('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
            console.log("change");
    })

    $('ul#topNav a').live('click', function(e){
            $.scrollTo('#content', 'slow');
            $("#content").hide();
            loadURL($(this).attr('href').fadeIn("6000"));
            e.preventDefault();
    });
    
// Top Nav Hijax

/*  $("ul#topNav a").live("click",function(e) {
        $.scrollTo('#content', 'slow');
                
        var url = $(this).attr("href") + " #content";   
        $("#content").hide().load(url).fadeIn("6000");
        e.preventDefault();
    }); */

// Bot Nav Hijax

    $("ul.bNav a").live("click",function(e) {
        $.scrollTo('#content', 'slow');
                
        var url = $(this).attr("href") + " #content";   
        $("#content").hide().load(url).fadeIn("6000");
        e.preventDefault();
    });

//Equal Height Columns

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div .col3").equalHeights();
                               });
```

This is the abridged HTML:

```
<ul id="topNav">
            <li>
            <a href="index.html" title="index" rel="address:/index"> Home </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="schedule.html" title="schedule" rel="address:/schedule"> Schedule </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="lodging.html" title="lodging" rel="address:/lodging"> Lodging </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="sponsors.html" title="sponsors" rel="address:/sponsors"> Sponsors </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="directions.html" title="directions" rel="address:/directions"> Directions </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="contact.html" title="contact" rel="address:/contact"> Contact </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        


 <div id="content" class="clearfix">
</div>
```

Also if you have any tips about the equalHeights columns please let me know, it seems as though this plugin is very simple but appears differently on each browser, I'm getting a lot of scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `change()` function, so if the address changes this will be executed:

```
$.address.change(function(event) {
    // your loading logic goes here
});
```